# android BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler give me response=null

Tags: android, httphandler

I've got this problem, basically I can receive the header from the server but the response is null, I don't understand why?
I saw the server log and everything works fine, I tried with curl request and even there everything works fine, but throught my app I'm not able to receive the response.

```
try {
                final String token2 = mPreferences.getString("auth_token", "");

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                final URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

                //create the hashmap with the parameters for Strings
                HashMap<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                paramMap.put("spot[title]", mtitle);
                paramMap.put("spot[address]", maddress);
                paramMap.put("spot[country]", mcountry);
                paramMap.put("spot[shot_level]", "easy");
                paramMap.put("spot[photos_attributes][0][description]", mdescription);

                params.put("spot[latitude]", googlelat);
                params.put("spot[longitude]", googlelng);
                params.put("", paramMap);
                //params.put("", paramMapInt);

                File myFile = new File(sglimagepath);
                try {
                    params.put("spot[photos_attributes][0][ref]", sourceFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                AsyncHttpClient client2 = new SyncHttpClient();
AsyncHttpClient client2 = new SyncHttpClient();
//check if needs this header or I can take off this and leave just the url+token2
            client2.addHeader("x-auth-token", token2);

            client2.post(String.valueOf(url), params, new BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler(String.valueOf(Looper.getMainLooper())) {

                /**
                 * Base abstract method, handling defined generic type
                 *
                 * @param statusCode      HTTP status line
                 * @param headers         response headers
                 * @param rawJsonResponse string of response, can be null
                 * @param response        response returned by {@link #parseResponse(String, boolean)}
                 */
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, String rawJsonResponse, Object response) {

                    onPostExecute((JSONObject)response);

                }

                /**
                 * Base abstract method, handling defined generic type
                 *
                 * @param statusCode    HTTP status line
                 * @param headers       response headers
                 * @param throwable     error thrown while processing request
                 * @param rawJsonData   raw string data returned if any
                 * @param errorResponse response returned by {@link #parseResponse(String, boolean)}
                 */
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, String rawJsonData, Object errorResponse) {

                }

                /**
                 * Should return deserialized instance of generic type, may return object for more vague
                 * handling
                 *
                 * @param rawJsonData response string, may be null
                 * @param isFailure   indicating if this method is called from onFailure or not
                 * @return object of generic type or possibly null if you choose so
                 * @throws Throwable allows you to throw anything from within deserializing JSON response
                 */
                @Override
                protected Object parseResponse(String rawJsonData, boolean isFailure) throws Throwable {
                    return null;
                }
```

I do this request because I'm sending to my server the image, the server response_code is 201 means that everything is alright, so the response will include the "user_id" then after receive the user_id I can make another request. Thanks for help

Comment: how you put img in the params ??

Comment: I edited: Basically I make a new File with the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
            final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

            //create the hashmap with the parameters for Strings
            params.add("spot[title]", mtitle);
            params.add("spot[address]", maddress);
            params.add("spot[country]", mcountry);
            params.add("spot[shot_level]", "easy");
            params.add("spot[photos_attributes][0][description]", mdescription);

            params.add("spot[latitude]", googlelat);
            params.add("spot[longitude]", googlelng);


            try {
        params.put("spot[photos_attributes][0][ref]", new File(sglimagepath));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and Watch the Log to see if file already found

edit
    here is my code ,, and its work fine

```
final RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
        requestParams.add("Event[user_id]", user_id);
        requestParams.add("Event[city]", city);
        requestParams.add("Event[title]", title);
        requestParams.add("Event[short_description]", shortDesc);
        requestParams.add("Event[description]", Desc);
        requestParams.add("Event[latitude]", lat);
        requestParams.add("Event[longitude]", longi);
        requestParams.add("Event[type_id]", type_id);
        try {
            Log.d("imgPath", "img path = " + img);
            File file = new File(img);
            requestParams.put("Event[img]" , file);
            requestParams.add("Event[img]" , imgName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        requestParams.setContentEncoding("utf-8");

        String url = ServerConnection.ipAdresss + ServerConnection.createEvents;

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
//        client.addHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
        client.post(url, requestParams, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {


            @Override
            public void onPostProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse response) {
                super.onPostProcessResponse(instance, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void sendResponseMessage(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                super.sendResponseMessage(response);
                Log.d("Failed", "failed " + response.getEntity().toString());


            }



            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("Failed", "failed " + throwable.getMessage());
                SUtility.makeToast(context, "Error = " + throwable.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                Log.d("Success", "success " + responseString);
                try {
                    ParseResp(responseString);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    SUtility.makeToast(context, "Error retrieving Data");
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                super.onFinish();
                Log.d("Success", "finish");
                if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();


            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I can't because the server want an Hash for that fields.. But the request works fine, is the response body that I'm not able to read. Basically I saw that the response from the server is without the Content-Length, so I think maybe is something wrong with "loopj" API

Comment: I tried but doesn't work, I receive the header but the response=null

Comment: why this method return null 

 @Override
                protected Object parseResponse(String rawJsonData, boolean isFailure) throws Throwable {
                    return null;
                }

Comment: Is already like that, I tried to return rawJsonData but doesn't do anything

Comment: if the problem is still occur please take a look at edit on my answer

Comment: I couldn't try it today...tomorrow as soon as I'll try I'll let you know...thanks man! ;)